# Add up/down arrows to keyboard toolbar in .NET MAUI?

Tags: ios, maui

I would like to add up and down arrows to the iOS keyboard that navigate between entries on my page similar to [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAykx.png).

I have followed the example found [here](https://github.com/moraismateus/MAUI-iOS-Keyboard-Done-Button) to add the Done button to the keyboard toolbar but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the arrows.

Using the example linked, I tried to replace this part:

```
var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, delegate
{
    this.PlatformView.EndEditing(true);
});
```

with something like this:

```
var nextButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FastForward, delegate
{
    this.PlatformView.NextResponder.BecomeFirstResponder();
});
```

but it doesn't seem like `NextResponder.BecomeFirstResponder()` is doing anything.

Comment: I think its called arrows natively but i am not able to find its documentation which is really weird

Comment: I didn't find any tech document about iOS up and down arrow on Keyboard toolbar. Can you accept [replacing `Done` with `Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry?view=net-maui-8.0#customize-the-return-key) to achieve entry jump?

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT I was trying to do that with the example I gave but I can't figure out how to get the next element to focus

Comment: I found the similar issue on github, you can follow this link: [iOS Keyboard Issue: 'Next' Button Missing on Entry](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18399).